# how use a function in render that have setState of an array

Tags: reactjs

how i can show the current week dates with week names in a row and also use navigator to show next and previous weeks of months

here is i am showing the week days of calendar and i ma use an array for week days and i want to use this array in another function through state but this way the react show me red flag of infinite loop how i use it?
please help me. Thanks in advance...

```
renderCells() {
  const { currentMonth, selectedDate } = this.state;
  const weekStart = dateFns.startOfWeek(currentMonth);
  const weekEnd = dateFns.endOfWeek(weekStart);
  const dateFormat = "DD";
  const rows = [];
  let days = [];
  let day = weekStart;
  let formattedDate = "";
  let dates = [];
  while (day <= weekEnd) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      formattedDate = dateFns.format(day, dateFormat);
      const date = moment(day, "mm-dd-yyyy").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      dates.push(date);
      days.push(
        <div
          className={`col cell ${
            !dateFns.isSameMonth(day, weekStart)
              ? "disabled"
              : dateFns.isSameDay(day, selectedDate)
              ? "selected"
              : ""
          }`}
        >
          <span className="number">{formattedDate}</span>
          <span className="bg">{formattedDate}</span>
        </div>
      );

      day = dateFns.addDays(day, 1);
    }
    rows.push(
      <div className="row" key={day}>
        {days}
      </div>
    );
  }

  {
    this.setState({ dates: dates });
  }

  return <div className="body">{rows}</div>, dates;
}

render() {
  return {this.renderCells()};
}
```

in this function i am using the state of array

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ meetingId: e.target.value });
  this.availableTime(e.target.value);
  console.log("meeting", e.target.value, this.state.dates);
};
```

Comment: In no way. You shouldn't update the state from render.

Comment: You never should do that